# Wordpress blog pagination problem, starting from page 3 gives error 404

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

This part of the code is causing the 404 from page 03 of the blog.
I've already tried to change the configuration and make it the same as the code, but it still doesn't work. This is happening when there are more than 7 posts.

```
             @php
              $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
              $posts_per_page = is_paged() ? 6 : 7;
              $args = [
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
                'paged' => $paged
              ];
              if ($category) {
                $args['tax_query'] = [
                  [
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $category->slug,
                  ]
                ];
              }
              if ($search) {
                $args['s'] = $search;
              }
              $i = 1;
            @endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the first three posts in your posts query, you can use `'offset'` in your query `args`.

```
'offset' => 3
```

Moreover if you want to query pages, the post type needs to be `page`.

```
'post_type' => 'page'
```

I think you get an error because you are querying posts and not pages, so there might be the 404 not found.